# Cocos2d-x how to draw in specific free form area

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, masking

Here https://github.com/mikeccy/cocos2dx-finger-paint/blob/master/Classes/HelloWorldScene.h and https://github.com/mikeccy/cocos2dx-finger-paint/blob/master/Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp you can see how a Sprite is being rendering in RenderTexture. What I want to add to this to make visible only the specific part in RenderTexture (canvas). I.e. I should apply a free form mask on it to be able to draw in a specific free form area.

How to do this in cocos2d-x 3.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer in cocos2d-x forum: http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/cocos2d-x-how-to-draw-in-specific-free-form-area/17623